# Workspace dialog is prompted twice during switch workspace in eclipse application. How to avoid this?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Workspace dialog is prompted twice during switch workspace in eclipse application. First when i say Switch Workspace -> Other , prompt comes up and then after saying OK the application restarts and prompt comes up again with the value selected during switch workspace. So functionality is fine but prompt comes up twice. How to make prompt come only once that is before restart?
This is eclipse rcp application.
I followed this article
http://hexapixel.com/2009/01/12/rcp-workspaces

Comment: Are you specifying the `-data @nodefault` somewhere? It may be overriding the workspace specified by the restart.

Comment: i have specified it ! but without it how will it prompt workspace by default? it will launch the eclipe default configuration?

Comment: It only uses the default if you click the 'use as default and don't prompt again' on the prompt dialog.

Comment: I tried without -data @noDefault but launching the eclipse application says **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change the location once it is set.**

Answer (score 0):

There is an option under Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown -> Worspaces where you can disable the option "Prompt for workspaces on startup".

Comment: I am writing a eclipse application! So I have my own code to prompt workspace and in that regardless of whether the prompt for workspace is checked or not the above error appears!

Comment: You might research what the code does, when this Preference option is selected and imitate that behaviour in your application.